# Keep on halving by integer division until x=1

Tags: python, integer, division

The function is to take a positive integer n and divide it by 2 (using integer division) until it reaches 1. The output should be the number of times that value is divided. My code so far is

```
def keep_halving(x):
    i=1
    for i in range(x):
        if x//2==0:
           return i
```

An example of how the function should run is

```
>>>keep_halving(4)
2
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem that you're experiencing? There are numerous errors in this code, BTW. In fact, it is quite entirely wrong. Have you tried to run it step by step and see what's happening (an activity also known as *debugging your code*)?

Comment: Also you will always return 1 every time your condition passes, which is definitely what you don't want to do. The `i` in your for loop is each value in your range. The `i=1` has no effect there.

Comment: @barak manos: I think Mihai Stefanescu would appreciate if you told him what exactly was wrong with his code and why and how he could improve it in order to achieve his goal (an activity also known as *constructive criticism*)

Comment: @Ukimiku: Haha, +1 for that last statement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
n = int(input("enter number"))
while n > 1:
    n //= 2
    print (n)
```

Input: `128`

Output:

```
enter number128
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
```

This will continuously divide by two using the `while` loop and stop when `n` gets to one.

Edit: I read your question too fast. Here is updated code:

```
count = 0
n = int(input("enter number"))
while n > 1:
    n //= 2
    print (n)
    count +=1
print (count)
```

This will add one onto `count` each time `n` is divided by two.

Input : `128`

Output :

```
enter number128
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
7
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize a while loop could be used here. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem - apologies for not understanding your code initially. I am actually making something similar for a binary converter. One of the algorithms for converting decimal to binary is to keep dividing by two and noting down remainders.

Comment: I simply did not include the print(n) which you left in the code in your answer. It ran as expected. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Yes, `print(n)` is not needed but I've always found it good practice to do something like that or similar to ensure that `n` is infact being divided by two each loop. No problem.

Comment: Of course. It is a simple proof that the function is indeed working as it should.